# (Bulk) Search and replace within photos

Tags: windows, image-processing, productivity, batch

I could need a tool that can search and replaces pieces of a photo (bitmap; pixel graphics).

All image editors I know have the ability to draw, clone or otherwise modify an image, but I don't know any program that would search a given image inside a large image and then replace that piece by another image of identical size.

Here's an example:

Source image:

[image: Source]

Search for:
[image: Search For]

Replace by:
[image: Replace By]

Result:

[image: Result]

Of course, if there's only two occurrences in one picture, I could do that manually. However, I have to do that with hundreds of occurrences in dozens of files.

It should work on Windows. There's no need for a UI. A command line tool is fine, since my main objective is bulk-processing. At the moment I don't care whether it's gratis or not.

It's main use will be for screenshots. The files formats of all files (input, search, replace) is lossless, so the derivation of pixels will be very low. Still, I would appreciate if there's a threshold like 90% match or so.

I don't want recommendations for programming this myself. I already have an idea on how to implement it. Possibly it's not even difficult. However, I'd prefer a tested application that already works.